# Calling C++ DLib from C# results in bad allocation exception

Tags: c#, c++, dlib

If I run my code directly in C++ it runs just fine. However when I invoke it from C# I get a bad allocation message. My C++ experience is really low but I feel based on everything I have read and modified, that this should work.

**My Situation**

Pass image path through facial recognition, it will then save/serialize the results to disk and return back the image's index in the array (function: int AddImageToCollection)

If I run my code with the main function I get perfect results (**Figure 1**) but if I run it through C# (**Figure 2**) I get the following:

I'm getting log 4-1 but not log 4-2, and the only error in e.what() is "bad allocation". I created a parameterless test function that is hard coded to return 5 and that works so it is isolated to this more complex function, and I believe it has to be related to passing in data to a const char*.

**Figure 1**

```
frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
shape_predictor sp;
anet_type net;

bool fileExists(const std::string& name) {
ifstream f(name.c_str());
return f.good();
}

void log(std::string name) {

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) try
{
string str = "C:\\images\\Me.jpg";
const char* c = str.c_str();

int whatIsMyIdx = AddImageToCollection(c);

cout << whatIsMyIdx << endl;

cin.get();
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}

int AddImageToCollection(const char* imagePath)
{
    deserialize("shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat") >> sp;
    deserialize("dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat") >> net;

    matrix<rgb_pixel> image;
    string imagePathStr(imagePath);

    load_image(image, imagePathStr);

    std::vector<matrix<rgb_pixel>> faces;

    if (fileExists("faces_in_collection.dat")) {
        deserialize("faces_in_collection.dat") >> faces;
    }

    auto facesDetected = detector(image);

    if (facesDetected.size() == 0) { return -1; }
    if (facesDetected.size() > 1) { return -2; }

    auto shape = sp(image, facesDetected[0]);

    log("4-1");

    matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
    extract_image_chip(image, get_face_chip_details(shape, 150, 0.25), face_chip);

    log("4-2");

    faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
    serialize("faces_in_collection.dat") << faces;

    std::vector<matrix<float, 0, 1>> face_descriptors;

    if (fileExists("face_descriptors_in_collection.dat")) {
        deserialize("face_descriptors_in_collection.dat") >> face_descriptors;
    }

    face_descriptors.push_back(net(faces[faces.size() - 1]));

    serialize("face_descriptors_in_collection.dat") << face_descriptors;

    return faces.size() - 1; //Return Image's Index in Array
}
```

**Figure 2**

```
    [DllImport("FacialRecognition.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int TestImageToCollection();

    [DllImport("FacialRecognition.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int AddImageToCollection([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string imagePath);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int whatIsMyTestIdx = TestImageToCollection();

        int whatIsMyIdx = AddImageToCollection(@"C:\images\Me.jpg");

        MessageBox.Show(whatIsMyIdx.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: You may want to use uint instead of int.  The files may be very large.  LPStr is bytes terminated with a '\0'.  Yet you are using it with jpg file which doesn't make a lot of sense.  It should be marshall as a byte[].  Since it is bytes you need a count also passed from the c++ to the c#.

Comment: The function only takes the path to the image, and in C++ it loads the image like so (matrix<rgb_pixel> image; string imagePathStr(imagePath); load_image(image, imagePathStr);)...but I may be misreading your comment but it sounds like you want me to send the bytes of the image to the function. Not sure that will solve my problem but willing to give it a try.

Comment: It looks like you are only passing the filename. The marshal UnmanagedType.LPStr converts the c# string (two byte characters) object to a byte[] terminated with a '\0'.  The c language code [char* imagePath] properly accept the string. I suspect the issue is with imagePathStr().  The compile for following with terminate with '\0': string str = "C:\\images\\Me.jpg"; imagePathStr() should do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adapt your code as following

in the DLL

`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int AddImageToCollection(LPCWSTR imagePath)
{
....
// you may need to convert from Unicode string to ANSI if you are calling function that accept ANSI strings
}`

and in the c# application

```
[DllImport("FacialRecognition.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern int AddImageToCollection(string imagePath);
```

and call your function like

```
int whatIsMyIdx = AddImageToCollection(@"C:\\images\\Me.jpg");
```

For the above to work correctly,  Do not forget to compile both application and Dll as Unicode. if they are differ you should adapt the correct export and import declarations.

Comment: I tried this earlier today and it wasn't working, then dummy me takes a closer look and I wasn't passing in a real image location anymore because I modified my code to post on here.  Well once I fixed that and applied your changes everything worked! Thank You!